goroutine problem-the data is not modified when operating on the same variable
This is a transaction execution simulation based on a dependency graph. I used goroutines to try to execute in parallel. The dependency graph records whether there is a data dependency relationship between the execution of transactions. Transactions without dependencies can be executed in parallel. But I encountered a problem, I found that the modification of monitorResult and duplicateG in the goroutine would not be successful, resulting in an infinite loop without changing the size of duplicateG. How to solve this problem?
ackage peers

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)
type Asset struct {
    AppraisedValue int
    ID             int
    version        int
}
type TxReadWriteSet struct {
    Reads  KVRead
    Writes KVWrite
}

// read set 
type KVRead struct {
    Key int
}

// write set 

type KVWriteType int


const (
    SET KVWriteType = iota 
    DEL                    
    INC                   
)

// KVWrite
type KVWrite struct {
    Key int
    Type  KVWriteType
    Value int
}

type singleTransaction struct {
    TransactionID   int
    TxReadWriteSet  TxReadWriteSet
    TransactionTime int32
}

type Graph struct {
    edges map[int][]int
    nodes map[int]bool
}
func SimulateWithGraph(transactions []singleTransaction, graph Graph) ([]Asset, []singleTransaction, []singleTransaction) {
    var successfulTransactions []singleTransaction
    var errorTransactions []singleTransaction
    monitorResult := GetWorldState()
    duplicateG := graph

    // Create a wait group to wait for all goroutines to complete
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var mutex sync.Mutex
    // Creates a channel for receiving successful and erroneous trades
    successfulCh := make(chan singleTransaction)
    errorCh := make(chan singleTransaction)
    // Transactions are executed in topologically sorted order
    for len(duplicateG.nodes) > 0 {
        // Gets a node with an entry degree of 0
        queue := getZeroInDegreeNodes(graph)
        // Execute transactions for nodes with a degree of 0
        txns := getTransaction(queue, transactions)
        for _, txn := range txns {
            
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(txn singleTransaction) {
                read := txn.TxReadWriteSet.Reads
                startVersion := monitorResult[read.Key].version

                // Check the write operation
                mutex.Lock()
                write := txn.TxReadWriteSet.Writes
                if write.Type == DEL && monitorResult[write.Key].AppraisedValue < write.Value {
                    errorCh <- txn
                    return
                }
                switch write.Type {
                case INC:
                    monitorResult[write.Key].AppraisedValue += write.Value
                case DEL:
                    monitorResult[write.Key].AppraisedValue -= write.Value
                case SET:
                    monitorResult[write.Key].AppraisedValue = write.Value
                }
                //Check that the version numbers are consistent before committing
                if monitorResult[read.Key].version != startVersion {
                    mutex.Unlock()
                    errorCh <- txn
                    return
                }
                monitorResult[write.Key].version++
                mutex.Unlock()
                successfulCh <- txn
                // Deletes the executed node
                delete(duplicateG.nodes, txn.TransactionID)
                delete(duplicateG.edges, txn.TransactionID)
                wg.Done()
            }(txn)
        }
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(successfulCh)
    close(errorCh)

    // Collect successful and erroneous trades
    for txn := range successfulCh {
        successfulTransactions = append(successfulTransactions, txn)
    }
    for txn := range errorCh {
        errorTransactions = append(errorTransactions, txn)
    }

    return monitorResult, successfulTransactions, errorTransactions
}

The nodes with 0 indegree in dependency graph should modify different asset values so I was wondering should I add a mutex and how to do it

You have a data race on duplicateG. Multiple goroutines are updating it concurrently.

@BurakSerdar So should I lock the duplicateG when I updating it?

Move unlock to before wg.Done. But that means most of the goroutine runs with a locked mutex, serializing all goroutines. Your solution would not benefit from concurrency unless you change how you work with data.

Alright I'll try, thanks for suggestions.

Do not start with goroutines, write synchronous code first. If that works, we can try to make it concurrent - where it is beneficial.
You do
                read := txn.TxReadWriteSet.Reads
                startVersion := monitorResult[read.Key].version

and
                if monitorResult[read.Key].version != startVersion {
                    // error
                    return
                }
                monitorResult[write.Key].version++

which means that goroutines fail if they have the same read key - that should probably be filtered before.
You mention that “Transactions without dependencies can be executed in parallel” - where do I see that? Also, what does a transaction do? If it's cheap, parallelizing might slow things down, if it's just CPU-bound starting more goroutines than your CPU has cores won't benefit your program.
Generally you shouldn't mix synchronization primitives with business logic so heavily - try to keep everything synchronous and look at which points you want to parallelize later, keeping most business logic synchronous.
